# First order difficult differential equation problem :

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(ax^2+bx^4)yy'+(c+dx^2+ex^4)y^3y'+fx^5y^3+gx^2y^4y'+hx^2y^5y'+kx^5y^2+nx^5=0$
I really have no idea how to solve this, I can't fit it into any of the schemes I already know.

Comment: I need to solve this problem for my MSc final project. My major is atomic physics.

Comment: All the coefficient are constant and real. This equation is from my work on a special condition in a plasma. Actually this equation was a second order one but i reduce it to first order.

Comment: No, i didn't find any closed form even when the coefficients are one.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time. All the coefficient are consist of temperature, quantum diffraction parameters, Mach number, densities and so on. I couldn't change them. some numerical methods (that i know) weren't helpful because i don't have initial value or any condition for the function.

Comment: For my work, I need the plot of 1/2y^2 . So how could i plot this?